# StreamWriter won't write to log file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

This code will create "output.txt" in C:\temp if it doesn't already exist. However, `log.WriteLine();` doesn't work for me. When I open the file, I don't see it. Why is this?

```
private static string LogFile = @"C:\Temp\output.txt";
private StreamWriter log;
if (!File.Exists(@"" + LogFile))
{
    log = new StreamWriter(@"" + LogFile);
}
else {
    log = File.AppendText(@"" + LogFile);
}
log.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now + "]: ");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the `StreamWriter`. It's best to use a `using` block for this, as it guarantees that the `StreamWriter` will be closed, even if an exception is thrown.

```
using (var log = GetLog()){
    log.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now + "]: ");
}
```

...

```
public StreamWriter GetLog(){
    if (!File.Exists(@"" + LogFile))
    {
        return new StreamWriter(@"" + LogFile);
    }
    else {
        return File.AppendText(@"" + LogFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an I/o Exception that the file is being used by another process, but this is the only part of my code that interacts with the file right now.

Comment: Then you have another instance of your program running or something like that. This is _your_ code, just refactored so that it can be called in the `using` block. The code works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little improvement in code to @John Saunders answer.

```
using (var log = GetLog())
{
    log.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now + "]: ");
}
```

...

```
public StreamWriter GetLog()
{
    return new StreamWriter(LogFile, File.Exists(LogFile));
}
```

The second parameter `StreamWriter` constructer takes determines `append` operation. Thus if file exists append otherwise not will do it. I think this is neater. And actually you can even do:

```
using (var log = new StreamWriter(LogFile, true))
{
    log.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now + "]: ");
}
```

Always appends, and if file does not exist creates it.

Comment: Is there a log writing standard that doesnt need this? Where I can just do File.Write("Line");

Comment: Rather, is there a way I can put

Answer (score 0):

If you are always appending the same thing to the file whether or not it already exists, you don't need the conditional.

`File.AppendText` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
private static string LogFile = @"C:\Temp\output.txt";

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LogFile)) 
{
    sw.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now + "]: ");
}
```

As John Saunders already said, you need to Dispose the stream writer, which will be done by putting it in a using statement.

([Documentation for StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))