# Using StreamWriter in VB.NET won't write to text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, streamwriter

I have read these sources ([first Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479952/how-do-i-force-write-to-file-using-streamwriter), [second Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357852/write-int-to-text-file-using-writer), [third Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853262/streamwriter-wont-write-to-log-file), [fourth Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854984/append-text-using-streamwriter) and [Microsoft streamwriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx)) and it did not solve the problem.

I have this code below.

**FIRST**

```
Private Sub WritePropertyLog(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal file_name As String, ByVal property_cd As String, _
                ByVal property_name As String, ByVal status As String)

    Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("Files\" + "DS_IKO_" + Date.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log")
        PropertyLog(folderPath, file_name, property_cd, property_name, status, w)
    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub PropertyLog(ByVal folderPath As String, ByVal file_name As String, ByVal property_cd As String, _
                ByVal property_name As String, ByVal status As String, ByVal w As TextWriter)

    w.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") + ", ")
    w.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", folderPath, file_name, property_cd, property_name, status)

End Sub
```

**SECOND**

```
' Logging each record ----------
Private Sub WriteRecordLog(ByVal row_number As String, ByVal columnB As String, ByVal columnC As String, _
                ByVal columnD As String, ByVal sekisan_cd As String, ByVal propertyCd As String, ByVal filename As String)

    Dim strFile As String = "Files\" + propertyCd = "_" + filename + "_" + Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log"
    Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(strFile)
        RecordLog(row_number, columnB, columnC, columnD, sekisan_cd, writer)
    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub RecordLog(ByVal row_number As String, ByVal columnB As String, ByVal columnC As String, _
                ByVal columnD As String, ByVal sekisan_cd As String, ByVal w As TextWriter)

    w.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row_number, columnB, columnC, columnD, sekisan_cd)

End Sub
```

I am trying to make a log file and as you can see, there is no much difference between the two, besides the variables. The **FIRST** code actually outputs or writes to `.log` but the **SECOND** code wouldn't. I needed both codes to write different logs and the *second code* executes first and executes more times than the *first code*.

What can the problem be?

I tried to add this in the second code:

```
    Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
    If (Not File.Exists(strFile)) Then
        fs = File.Create(strFile)
    End If
```

And I even tried the `.flush()` and `.close()` and the other way which is not:

```
Using
End Using
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Have you used the debugger?

Comment: In general, use `Path.Combine` to build paths. It makes it a lot easier and more readable.

Comment: Are you sure about your file path? Are you looking in the correct folder? You are using *relative* paths, which means that during debugging you are writing to `bin/debug/Files`

Comment: `propertyCd = "_"` doesn't look right - was that deliberate?

Comment: Use `String.Format` to create the file name instead of concatenating strings to avoid misspellings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is your problem:

```
Dim strFile As String = "Files\" + propertyCd = "_" + filename + "_" + Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log"
```

Especially this part:

```
propertyCd = "_"
```

That is a comparison and returns either `True` or `False`.

In general I would use `String.Format` for your file name and `Path.Combine` to build the path.

```
Dim file = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.log", 
    propertyCd, filename, Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")) 
Dim strFile As String = Path.Combine("Files", file)
```

Also, use the debugger to check the values of variables at runtime.

Comment: I can't believe that's it... I spent two whole hours trying to solve it. Thanks!